# Flexbox middle column centering issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How can I keep the left column from growing? Want the logo column to be centered and the left and right column to take the resulting space. Made a fiddle to demonstrate the effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/roberthenniger/1qyeghm7/

```
.nav-column:nth-child(1), .nav-column:nth-child(3) {
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-basis:50%;
}
```

We have a javascript which checks the content width and changes then to different layout but still I don't want the outer columns to grow. I understand that it grows because in the left there is still room left.

```css
body .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
body .nav span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  flex-basis: 160px;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Menu Links with long content but it should not overlap and not push to the right</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>here it looks fine</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that pushes the outer columns out of the container. And we need the white-space:nowrap to make it possible to calculate the width of the elements. We want to see when they wrap, then we show a different view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to the *right* and *left* columns and add an *ellipsis* for a long `span` (I noticed that you have `white-space: nowrap` for the content) by adding:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

See demo below:

```css
body .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
body .nav span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  /*flex-basis: 50%;*/
  flex: 1; /* ADDED */
  overflow: hidden; /* ADDED */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* ADDED */
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  flex-basis: 160px;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  /*flex-basis: 50%;*/
  flex: 1; /* ADDED */
  overflow: hidden; /* ADDED */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Menu Links with long content but it should not overlap and not push to the right</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>here it looks fine</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that only adding the *ellipsis* will center your logo.

```css
body .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
body .nav span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden; /* ADDED */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* ADDED */
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  flex-basis: 160px;
}
body .nav .nav-column:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden; /* ADDED */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Menu Links with long content but it should not overlap and not push to the right</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>here it looks fine</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-column">
    <span>CTA</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats nice but i "want" the overflow so that i can calculate with javascript if an element is causing an overflow. You have any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Just saw that the ellipsis setting was on the parent and has no effect on the child, thats good. So we can force the overflow.

Comment: Why do you think that only the ellipsis will center the logo? Would say that the overflow:hidden is the setting i was looking for to prevent the columns from eating the unused space. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Rob yeah I meant *overflow* acutually... as the code was having ellipsis, I wrote it like that :)